# Difference between [table1.column1=table2.column1] and [table1.column1=1 AND table2.column1=1]

Tags: mysql

I don't know if there are any terms for these statements:
I have table1 and table2

table1

```
id link_id
1     1
1     2
1     3

table2

id link_url
1     www.a
2     www.b
3     www.c
```

And two different MYSQL Statements:

```
SELECT table1.id as id, table2.link_url as link_url FROM table1, table2  WHERE table1.link_id =1 and table2.id=1

SELECT table1.id as id, table2.link_url as link_url FROM table1, table2  WHERE table1.link_id=table2.id
```

I understand that they both return the same results.

Is there any difference in using either of them or doesn't it matter at all?

Comment: Many. One is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is Difference.
First Statement Returns only one row as you have set `table1.link_id=1 and table2.id=1`

Second Statement will Return every row which have link_id value in table1 similar to id value table2

Answer (score 0):

`link_id=table2.id` select all data of your table where both coloumn are same .But  `WHERE table1.link_id =1 and table2.id=1` select data where link_id is 1 and id is 1.... both are diffrent

But USE JOIN is good option :-

```
SELECT table1.id as id, table2.link_url as link_url 
FROM table1 join  table2  
on table1.link_id=table2.id
WHERE table1.link_id =1
```